# debug TcpClient and TcpListener on the same machine

Tags: .net, sockets

New to network programming here.

I have a two piece application. I am trying to debug it locally.
Service listens for connections on `new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 3000)`.
Calling `tcpClient.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3000))` throws `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3000`. Windows firewall is off.

Am I doing something fundamentally stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call the `Start` method on the TcpListener to get it working, or it will not accept any connection.

I have tested and this snippet works :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int port = 5124;

            var myListener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
            myListener.Start();

            var tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            tcpClient.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port));

            tcpClient.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am calling `Start()` for sure. Oddly enough when I changed to your port (I was using port 3000 before) my code worked as well. Is it possible to clog up a port by not closing client or listener properly?  Shouldn't any unmanaged resources get cleaned up when application exits?

Comment: I don't know, I would just not use that port... see here: http://www.pc-library.com/ports/tcp-udp-port/3000/

Comment: Hmm interesting... But anyway, that answers my question to wherever I am doing anything fundamentally wrong.